# How to scan a JS file using Fortify security scan software

Tags: javascript, fortify

Can anybody let me know the steps of how to scan a JS file using Fortify security scan software. I surfed for user guide, but couldn't get any for this.

My scan tool page looks likes this
      https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXOI4.jpg
Thanks

Comment: You are using Fortify On-Demand, which is different from using Fortify directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Scan Wizard which comes with Fortify. Add the root of your project and click next. Fortify will pick up all the javascript .js files; one caveat is that only Javascript 1.8 and above is supported. Click Finish. Run the Fortify.bat file created at the root location of your project. The same generates the .fpr file.

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot shows the Fortify On Demand website.
You need to upload your javascript file to the FOD website, but I don't know how to do this.
Click on one of the blue "Community", "Learn" or "Support" buttons, and ask there.